# Whats the right way to impliment a login view using prism 4

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism-4

I am trying to create a login control, pretty simple stuff...just using a usercontrol with a couple of labels, textboxes and buttons. My problem here is im using prism and  i dont know the right way to impliment the logic. Since im writing everything myself, ive been spoiled by asp.net, im really kinda lost. Ive seen a few articles but nothing that really gives me a clear cut idea. I think i should be using delegate commands to handle the button click events but thats about as much as ive got. Any help or articles that may help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
So Confused!!!

Answer (score 0):

see [Chronos wpf application](http://chronoswpf.codeplex.com/) it will be give you some good clues